# Merging tags [sapui5] and [sapui]

Tags: discussion, tags

To me, the descriptions of [[sapui]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui) and [[sapui5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sapui5) look very similar and cover the same topic. I'm unsure on how they came into being, but I believe they should be merged.

Answer (score 5):

Agreed. "sapui" is not a proper term describing a concrete technology. [sapui5] should be the valid one.